# Adding delay in program C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, delay

In my `WP7` app, player draws a line and then CPU draws a line. I want CPU to wait for 5 sec before processing and drawing the line. I use this `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);`just after player is done drawing. But the player's line is not drawn completely and system goes to sleep and after 5 sec both lines are drawn. How to complete the player's line and then to start the delay ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000) will freeze your app and your UI. Your app will surely not pass certification because of this.

Use DispatcherTimer.
Follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DispatcherTimer to add some delay immediately after the player's turn.

This is typically what you could do:

Class Variables:

```
DispatcherTimer delayTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
int timesTicked = 0;
```

In your Constructor:

```
delayTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5000);
delayTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
```

Handler:

```
void delayTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    timesTicked++;
    if(timesTicked == 2)
    {
      timesTicked = 0;
      delayTimer.Stop();
      RunCPU();
    }
}
```

The above tracks the amount of times the Timer has ticked and after two ticks, it calls the RunCPU method. Note that the above will 10 seconds. You can play around with the numbers to find a niche for the delay.

Answer (score -2):

Try with Application.DoEvents(); before sleep.